How to set path for howdy?
My OS info:
uname -a
Linux hello 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

howdy already installed:
sudo apt list howdy
Listing... Done
howdy/now 2.6.1 all [installed,local]

Call howdy:
howdy
bash: howdy: command not found
which howdy |wc -l
0
dpkg -L howdy | grep bin|wc -l
0

How to set path for howdy?

dpkg -L howdy | grep bin

Assuming that there were no errors during installation, you should have a symlink /usr/local/bin/howdy pointing at /lib/security/howdy/cli.py. Both of these should be executable (755).
I found this by downloading the prebuilt .deb package from the source repo, opening it (rather than installing it), and viewing its postinst script (in the DEBIAN directory).
The script is rather long, so I won't include the whole thing here, but the relevant hunk is near the end:
# Allow anyone to execute the python CLI
os.chmod("/lib/security/howdy", 0o755)
os.chmod("/lib/security/howdy/cli.py", 0o755)
handleStatus(sc(["chmod 755 -R /lib/security/howdy/cli"], shell=True))
print("Permissions set")

# Make the CLI executable as howdy
os.symlink("/lib/security/howdy/cli.py", "/usr/local/bin/howdy")
os.chmod("/usr/local/bin/howdy", 0o755)
print("Howdy command installed")

I would begin by checking that you have the symlink in /usr/local/bin, the python file that it points at, and that both are executable. If that is not the case, then it implies a problem during installation. Otherwise I would check that /usr/local/bin is on your path.

That is ... horrifying. What even is the point of using a deb package if it's going to do all that in a script?

@muru I guess, deb packages provide a unified interface to install various kind of applications with package managers, including binaries/source and requirements.

@Green绿色 that sounds like some marketing speak, but it seems this package misses the point of deb packages altogether. The package itself should contain symlinks, files with correct permissions, etc., instead of doing all that in a maintainer script. This just reeks of creating a package for the sake of ticking a box somewhere.

@muru Can you publish a software that is not packaged as deb in apt? The box the author had to tick might just be that apt requires debs. (I have no actual experience in packaging for apt, so I genuinely don't know)

@Green绿色 the question is meaningless. It's like asking if you can write an essay not in words.

sudo ln /lib/security/howdy/cli.py /usr/local/bin/howdy

